# Within Span, how to change the color of text

Tags: html, css

I hate to press my luck asking for help, but here I go anyway --

I got this code from w3schools.com but cannot figure out how to make the word OPEN in the HTML code a different color.  It is currently black, I want it white.  The other colors I changed because my actual page has a black background.  Sorry the code is so long, I figured better to have too much than not enough.  Here is the code I currently have:

**HTML**

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
<a href="#">About</a>
<a href="#">Services</a>
<a href="#">Clients</a>
<a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<p>Click on the element below to open the menu</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>

<script>
function openNav() {
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #DD0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #2707AB;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #818181;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```css
body {
font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #DD0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #2707AB;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #818181;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
.opencolor
{
  color:tan;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
<a href="#">About</a>
<a href="#">Services</a>
<a href="#">Clients</a>
<a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<p>Click on the element below to open the menu</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer;">&#9776; </span><span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer;" class="opencolor" onclick="openNav()">open</span>

<script>
function openNav() {
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for changin the colour of open try this.

```
    <p>Click on the element below to open the menu</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; <font color="red">open</font></span>
```

or

```
 <p>Click on the element below to open the menu</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; <span style="color:blue;">open</span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take one class inside  and write css for that class .

```
<span class="foo" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
```

css

```
.foo{
        font-size:30px;
        cursor:pointer;
        color:#fff;
    }
```

and if you want only that bar color to change use that css with this html

```
<div  onclick="openNav()"><span class="bar">&#9776;</span> open</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the word "open" in another span to apply inline styling to it.

`...<span style="color:white;">open</span>...`